# "Buy Items" with SQL Transaction in EF Core, if user send many requests, items are bought even if they can't afford it

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a game where the user can buy items with ingame coins. The coins and the items are stored in a SQL database, and user should (obviously) only be able to buy items that they can afford.

The Problem with this code is that if the user spams many requests at the same time, he gets more items than he can afford since the next request is sent before the previous one is done updating the database.

**How do I prevent this "spam posting bug"?**

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<UserProfile>> BuyItem(ShopItem item)
{
    try
    {
        //Begin Transaction
        using var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        var user = await _context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Name == User.Identity.Name);
        await _context.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
        
        //If user can afford the item
        if (user.Coins >= item.Price)
        {
            //Decrease money from user
            user.Coins -= item.Price;
            _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //Create new item in database that belongs to the user who bought it
            var userItem = new UserItem()
            {
                ShopItemId = item.Id,
                UserProfileId = user.Id
            };
            _context.UserItems.Add(userItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            //Throw exception, this should rollback the transaction?
            throw new Exception();
        }
        //End Transaction
        _context.Database.CloseConnection();
        transaction.Commit();

        return new JsonResult(user);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove this line `_context.Database.CloseConnection();`. Context should be opened before `Commit`

Comment: You might need a `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level for your transaction like this `_context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)`, as you are reading the data into the client modifying and saving it back. Much better to write a stored procedure which does all of this in a transaction, and call it from here.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I get the same result though

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you very much! (IsolationLevel.Serializable) was the answer

Comment: I do strongly recommend a stored procedure though, as `SERIALIZABLE` is going to causing blocking and deadlocking problems under heavy usage, and that is not solvable with EF, you'd need a customized procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)

> Specifies the following:
>
> - Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet
>   committed by other transactions.
> - No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the
>   current transaction until the current transaction completes.
> - Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would
>   fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current
>   transaction until the current transaction completes.

Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15